# Text disappears when resizing window

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am taking a course and I got stuck at one of my homeworks. I am supposed to use media queries to make the site responsive and mostly it works as supposed to, but when I get to certain value, my text disappears.. It happens at window width 680px to 690px and I just have noooooo idea, why.. it should be covered by @media (max-width: 700px) statement, shouldn´t it? And my css works with all the other window widths just fine.. 
Any ideas?

```css
/**
 * GENERAL
 */
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* clearfix */
.group:before,
.group:after { content: " "; display: table; }
.group:after { clear: both; }


body {
 color: #2f2f2f;
 font: 0.9em/1.35em 'Avant Garde', 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
 padding: 1.4em;
 max-width: 100%;
}

p {
 margin: 0;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.container {
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

article {
 width: 31.25%; /*width: 300px;*/
 float: left;
 margin: 0 1.04%; /*margin: 0 10px;*/
}

.text {
 text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 1010px) {
 body {
  font-size: 0.85em;
  line-height: 1.28em;
  padding: 1em;
 }

 h3 {
  font-size: 1.05em;
  margin: 0.7em;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 940px) {
 body {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  line-height: 1.13em;
  padding: 0.5em;
 }

 h3 {
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  font-size: 1em;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 780px) {
 article {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 2.55% 0;
 }

 .image {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }

 .text {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 55%;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }

}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
 article {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
 }

 .image, .text {
  display: block;
 }

 .text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  color: #444;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  z-index: 2;
 }

 h3 {
  color: #323232;
 }

 .image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container group">

  <article>
   <header class="image">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Montauk_Point_Lighthouse.jpg/300px-Montauk_Point_Lighthouse.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Fionna">
   </header>
   <div class="text">
    <h3>Fionna</h3>
    <p>An alternate, female version of Finn, Fionna the human is just as brave, adventurous and awesome as her male counterpart as she faces off against her enemy, the Ice Queen.</p>
   </div>
  </article>


  <article>
   <header class="image">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Montauk_Point_Lighthouse.jpg/300px-Montauk_Point_Lighthouse.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Peppermint Butler">
   </header>
   <div class="text">
    <h3>Peppermint Butler</h3>
    <p>Peppermint Butler is an inhabitant of the Candy Kingdom and loyal butler to Princess Bubblegum. He has a mysterious past and an undefined relationship with Death.</p>
   </div>
  </article>


  <article>
   <header class="image">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Montauk_Point_Lighthouse.jpg/300px-Montauk_Point_Lighthouse.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Flame Princess">
   </header>
   <div class="text">
    <h3>Flame Princess</h3>
    <p>Flame Princess is a hot-headed princess from the Fire Kingdom and Finn's new crush. Her flame powers are tied to her emotions, and she's been known to anger quite easily.
    <p>
   </div>
  </article>
 </div>
```

Comment: and apparently, as I have posted this, the text disappears at a little different width values, but not too different.. like somewhere around 700px.. I don´t understand at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`header.image` and `div.text` are both inline-block elements when the view width is less than 780px. So the both of them are trying to share the width of the parent `article` element. *But*, `div-text` has a max-width of 55%, so it's overflowing its sibling and parent, and moves to the next line. But now that it's on the next line, it's partially hidden by the image container, but the `overflow:hidden` on its parent makes it completely hidden.

If you change the `max-width` of `div.text` to 50%, you shouldn't get any more overflow issues when resizing:

```css
/**
 * GENERAL
 */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


/* clearfix */

.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.group:after {
  clear: both;
}

body {
  color: #2f2f2f;
  font: 0.9em/1.35em 'Avant Garde', 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
  padding: 1.4em;
  max-width: 100%;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

article {
  width: 31.25%;
  /*width: 300px;*/
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1.04%;
  /*margin: 0 10px;*/
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 1010px) {
  body {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    line-height: 1.28em;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.05em;
    margin: 0.7em;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 940px) {
  body {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    line-height: 1.13em;
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  h3 {
    margin: 0.25em 0;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 780px) {
  article {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 2.55% 0;
  }
  .image {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .text {
    display: inline-block;
    /*max-width: 55%;*/
    max-width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  article {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px auto;
  }
  .image,
  .text {
    display: block;
  }
  .text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: none;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color: #444;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  h3 {
    color: #323232;
  }
  .image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container group">

  <article>
    <header class="image">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Montauk_Point_Lighthouse.jpg/300px-Montauk_Point_Lighthouse.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Fionna">
    </header>
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Fionna</h3>
      <p>An alternate, female version of Finn, Fionna the human is just as brave, adventurous and awesome as her male counterpart as she faces off against her enemy, the Ice Queen.</p>
    </div>
  </article>


  <article>
    <header class="image">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Montauk_Point_Lighthouse.jpg/300px-Montauk_Point_Lighthouse.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Peppermint Butler">
    </header>
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Peppermint Butler</h3>
      <p>Peppermint Butler is an inhabitant of the Candy Kingdom and loyal butler to Princess Bubblegum. He has a mysterious past and an undefined relationship with Death.</p>
    </div>
  </article>


  <article>
    <header class="image">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/54/Montauk_Point_Lighthouse.jpg/300px-Montauk_Point_Lighthouse.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Flame Princess">
    </header>
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Flame Princess</h3>
      <p>Flame Princess is a hot-headed princess from the Fire Kingdom and Finn's new crush. Her flame powers are tied to her emotions, and she's been known to anger quite easily.
        <p>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```